# How to generate random variates from random variables with known density?

Tags: distributions, random-generation

Given a random number generator to produce random variables with a probability density function $f(x)$, how to generate random variables with probability density function $g(x)?$

Comment: $G^{-1}(F(X))$ where $F(\cdot)$ is the CDF corresponding to $f(x)$ and $G(\cdot)$ corresponding to $g(x)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: thanks! But isn't this very inefficient because function inversion is involved? Also one needs to integrate and then calculate inverse.

Comment: There is nothing to integrate, and $G^{-1}$ is a **fixed** function. Also, **usually**, a random number generator produces samples from $U(0,1)$ so that $F(X)=X$ which requires no computation. As an example, if $X \sim U(0,1)$, then $-\ln(X)$ is an exponential random variable.  Lookit! No integration, no inverse computation, just using a function available in all math libraries to get samples from an exponential distribution.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I was saying if one is given with $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as pdf. In that case, how do you get $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ (as you said, they are CDF) without integration? Also, you clearly used $G^{-1}$ which is the inverse of $G$, without function inversion, how do you compute $G^{-1}(F(x))?$

Comment: The point you are missing is that it is only necessary to find the functions $F$ and $G^{-1}$ **once**, e.g. $F(X)=X$ and $G^{-1}(X) = -\ln(X)$, and then program them into a subroutine that, when given a sample $X$ from your random number generator, will return $G^{-1}(F(X))$, e.g. given $X$, return $-\ln(X)$.  It is **not** necessary to do integrations and function inversions as you call them after generating each random sample $X_i$.  There is a _one-time_ cost of figuring out what these functions are; not a per-sample cost of integration and inversion that you seem to be so concerned about.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the pdf's for both, and the distribution from which you can sample, $f(x)$, encloses the distribution from which you want to sample, $g(x)$ (or can be made to do so by multiplying the likelihoods by some constant $c$), you can use an [accept-reject algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).  The gist of this approach is as follows:

1. Draw a value from $f(x)$
2. At that x-value, form a ratio, $r=g(x)/f(x)$
3. Draw a value, $u$, from a uniform distribution on the interval (0,1)
4. If $u\le r$, then accept that $x$ and store it
5. If $u>r$, then reject that $x$ and start over
6. Continue until you have $N$ realized values

Note that accept-reject algorithms are notoriously sluggish, even if you end up accepting all x-values, there are several extra steps for each draw.  To optimize the performance of this approach, try to pick an $f(x)$ that is as close to (i.e., as little above) $g(x)$ as possible, so that you accept as high a percentage as you can.